# Library file error while using a Third party component( INA138)

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ltspice, current-measurement, high-side

I want to use the INA138 as a current sensing amplifier but its symbol is not available in Ltspice so I downloaded the .lib File from https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sbom140 here.

I then opened the file in Ltspice and clicked on the (.subckt INA138  + - Vs GND OUT) name of the component besides the subckt title and thus right clicked on it to create a symbol. I updated the model file for the symbol and saved it but when I use it I am getting an error stating

"Could not open the library file"

If anybody knows how to solve this please respond. Thank You

Comment: Creating custom symbols hard-codes the path into the symbol. Edit the `.asy` file with a text editor and delete the line `SYMATTR ModelFile ...`. Then make sure your library resides in a correct location before using `.lib /path/to/library.sub`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: You already have a very similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/508046/95619). Does the very detailed answer provide any clues to you? Answer which you haven't checked.