# creating symbol for Transmission gate switch in ltspice

Tags: ltspice, logic-gates, symbol, transmission, subcircuit

[image: transmission gate symbol and circuit]

I need to create a symbol of transmission gate to use but when putting its symbol I get a message "unknown subcircuit called in xx1_nc01_nc02_nc03_nc04
how may I fix it?

Comment: Consult the manual on how to create a symbol from a schematic.

Comment: And if you probably do not want to connect the transistor bodies to the sources.

Comment: If this is not a [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372297/95619), it's at least very similar.