# How to simulate a short on LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, parameters

I'm trying to simulate two scenarios in LTspice. One is when things are ok. The second is when a short happens.
As you can imagine I'm a beginner with LTspice. At first I was just putting a resistor at the output of my circuit to simulate my load. And when I wanted to simulate the short, I put the resitor at 1 mohm.

But I'd like to "automate" this. A short that happens after the sim has been running for some time.

I tried this. But I don't have a perfect zero when shorted.

[image]

But I've seen another solution:

[image]

When I do this I get the error : Can't find the definition model "SW".

EDIT: Thanks to Winny and his [link](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspiceiv-voltage-controlled-switches.html#) I was able to correctly set up my short. You can also find more about switches in a post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372278/spdt-in-ltspice/372297#372297)

Comment: Hit F2, then look under the "Misc" folder and find "jumper." For a way to connect two different nodes, anyway. That may achieve what you want. Let me know, if not.

Comment: @jonk but the jumper doesn"t turn ON or OFF "alone"?

Comment: For your switch problem, you need to add a spice directive as outlined here: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspiceiv-voltage-controlled-switches.html# and name your switch to the same as in the spice directive.

Comment: @Neeko I was thinking you could just add it or remove it, running each time. Up to you. The other option is the voltage controlled switch you had trouble with. I was just trying to avoid writing up details on that. (I've written about it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372297/38098), for example.)

Comment: @winny Thanks for the link. It was detailing at the end how to do a proper short with that switch.

Comment: @jonk Before posting I search for " switch" in the research bar but your post didn"t come up...

Comment: @Neeko Well, hopefully the link helps.