# How to implement a power multiplexer in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice

I need to implement what I will describe as a power multiplexer for use in testing other circuits in LTSpice.

The idea is to be able to switch a range of loads and sources into the output of the circuit I am working on.  For example, I might want to test with a pure 100K resistive load, pure 1K resistive load, 10uF capacitive load, 1A current source (load or source, depending on how you look at it), inductive load, short to ground, short to V+, etc.

Imagine a bank of physical switches connected to the UUT.  You use this bank of switches to see how it reacts to being connected to a range of circuits/loads/sources/sinks.

I also want to keep it simple, in the sense that it should create minimal simulation load.

Finally, rather than control it digitally, I want to control channel selection using a voltage.  This allows for using PWL ramps or stairsteps and automating the testing with all available loads and sources.

Here's what I've come-up with.  It works.  Can it be improved?

[image: LTSpice Power Multiplexer]

Only showing a few channels in the image, here's the entire model (includes extra hardware for testing):

```
    Version 4
SHEET 1 3304 2580
WIRE 288 336 128 336
WIRE 256 400 128 400
WIRE 368 400 256 400
WIRE 512 400 368 400
WIRE 1024 400 960 400
WIRE 1296 400 1264 400
WIRE 1408 400 1376 400
WIRE 128 432 128 400
WIRE 288 432 288 336
WIRE 320 432 288 432
WIRE 464 432 320 432
WIRE 368 448 368 400
WIRE 512 448 512 400
WIRE 1024 448 1024 400
WIRE 320 464 320 432
WIRE 464 464 464 432
WIRE 976 464 608 464
WIRE 976 512 640 512
WIRE 2208 512 2080 512
WIRE 320 544 320 512
WIRE 464 544 464 512
WIRE 464 544 320 544
WIRE 512 544 512 528
WIRE 608 544 608 464
WIRE 608 544 512 544
WIRE 688 544 608 544
WIRE 848 544 768 544
WIRE 2080 560 2080 512
WIRE 128 576 128 512
WIRE 320 576 320 544
WIRE 368 576 368 528
WIRE 640 576 640 512
WIRE 640 576 368 576
WIRE 688 576 640 576
WIRE 848 576 848 544
WIRE 848 576 768 576
WIRE 1024 576 1024 528
WIRE 1264 576 1264 400
WIRE 1264 576 1024 576
WIRE 848 608 848 576
WIRE 256 656 256 400
WIRE 368 656 256 656
WIRE 512 656 368 656
WIRE 1024 656 960 656
WIRE 2080 672 2080 640
WIRE 288 688 288 432
WIRE 320 688 288 688
WIRE 464 688 320 688
WIRE 368 704 368 656
WIRE 512 704 512 656
WIRE 1024 704 1024 656
WIRE 320 720 320 688
WIRE 464 720 464 688
WIRE 976 720 608 720
WIRE 976 768 640 768
WIRE 320 800 320 768
WIRE 464 800 464 768
WIRE 464 800 320 800
WIRE 512 800 512 784
WIRE 608 800 608 720
WIRE 608 800 512 800
WIRE 688 800 608 800
WIRE 848 800 768 800
WIRE 2208 816 2080 816
WIRE 320 832 320 800
WIRE 368 832 368 784
WIRE 640 832 640 768
WIRE 640 832 368 832
WIRE 688 832 640 832
WIRE 848 832 848 800
WIRE 848 832 768 832
WIRE 1024 832 1024 784
WIRE 1264 832 1264 576
WIRE 1264 832 1024 832
WIRE 2080 848 2080 816
WIRE 848 864 848 832
WIRE 256 912 256 656
WIRE 368 912 256 912
WIRE 512 912 368 912
WIRE 1024 912 960 912
WIRE 288 944 288 688
WIRE 320 944 288 944
WIRE 464 944 320 944
WIRE 368 960 368 912
WIRE 512 960 512 912
WIRE 1024 960 1024 912
WIRE 2080 960 2080 928
WIRE 320 976 320 944
WIRE 464 976 464 944
WIRE 976 976 608 976
WIRE 976 1024 640 1024
WIRE 2208 1040 2080 1040
WIRE 320 1056 320 1024
WIRE 464 1056 464 1024
WIRE 464 1056 320 1056
WIRE 512 1056 512 1040
WIRE 608 1056 608 976
WIRE 608 1056 512 1056
WIRE 688 1056 608 1056
WIRE 848 1056 768 1056
WIRE 2080 1072 2080 1040
WIRE 320 1088 320 1056
WIRE 368 1088 368 1040
WIRE 640 1088 640 1024
WIRE 640 1088 368 1088
WIRE 688 1088 640 1088
WIRE 848 1088 848 1056
WIRE 848 1088 768 1088
WIRE 1024 1088 1024 1040
WIRE 1264 1088 1264 832
WIRE 1264 1088 1024 1088
WIRE 848 1120 848 1088
WIRE 256 1168 256 912
WIRE 368 1168 256 1168
WIRE 512 1168 368 1168
WIRE 1024 1168 960 1168
WIRE 2080 1184 2080 1152
WIRE 288 1200 288 944
WIRE 320 1200 288 1200
WIRE 464 1200 320 1200
WIRE 368 1216 368 1168
WIRE 512 1216 512 1168
WIRE 1024 1216 1024 1168
WIRE 320 1232 320 1200
WIRE 464 1232 464 1200
WIRE 976 1232 608 1232
WIRE 2208 1264 2080 1264
WIRE 976 1280 640 1280
WIRE 2080 1296 2080 1264
WIRE 320 1312 320 1280
WIRE 464 1312 464 1280
WIRE 464 1312 320 1312
WIRE 512 1312 512 1296
WIRE 608 1312 608 1232
WIRE 608 1312 512 1312
WIRE 688 1312 608 1312
WIRE 848 1312 768 1312
WIRE 320 1344 320 1312
WIRE 368 1344 368 1296
WIRE 640 1344 640 1280
WIRE 640 1344 368 1344
WIRE 688 1344 640 1344
WIRE 848 1344 848 1312
WIRE 848 1344 768 1344
WIRE 1024 1344 1024 1296
WIRE 1264 1344 1264 1088
WIRE 1264 1344 1024 1344
WIRE 848 1376 848 1344
WIRE 2080 1408 2080 1376
WIRE 256 1424 256 1168
WIRE 368 1424 256 1424
WIRE 512 1424 368 1424
WIRE 1024 1424 960 1424
WIRE 288 1456 288 1200
WIRE 320 1456 288 1456
WIRE 464 1456 320 1456
WIRE 368 1472 368 1424
WIRE 512 1472 512 1424
WIRE 1024 1472 1024 1424
WIRE 320 1488 320 1456
WIRE 464 1488 464 1456
WIRE 976 1488 608 1488
WIRE 2208 1488 2080 1488
WIRE 2080 1520 2080 1488
WIRE 976 1536 640 1536
WIRE 320 1568 320 1536
WIRE 464 1568 464 1536
WIRE 464 1568 320 1568
WIRE 512 1568 512 1552
WIRE 608 1568 608 1488
WIRE 608 1568 512 1568
WIRE 688 1568 608 1568
WIRE 848 1568 768 1568
WIRE 320 1600 320 1568
WIRE 368 1600 368 1552
WIRE 640 1600 640 1536
WIRE 640 1600 368 1600
WIRE 688 1600 640 1600
WIRE 848 1600 848 1568
WIRE 848 1600 768 1600
WIRE 1024 1600 1024 1552
WIRE 1264 1600 1264 1344
WIRE 1264 1600 1024 1600
WIRE 848 1632 848 1600
WIRE 2080 1632 2080 1600
WIRE 256 1680 256 1424
WIRE 368 1680 256 1680
WIRE 512 1680 368 1680
WIRE 1024 1680 960 1680
WIRE 288 1712 288 1456
WIRE 320 1712 288 1712
WIRE 464 1712 320 1712
WIRE 2208 1712 2080 1712
WIRE 368 1728 368 1680
WIRE 512 1728 512 1680
WIRE 1024 1728 1024 1680
WIRE 320 1744 320 1712
WIRE 464 1744 464 1712
WIRE 976 1744 608 1744
WIRE 2080 1744 2080 1712
WIRE 976 1792 640 1792
WIRE 320 1824 320 1792
WIRE 464 1824 464 1792
WIRE 464 1824 320 1824
WIRE 512 1824 512 1808
WIRE 608 1824 608 1744
WIRE 608 1824 512 1824
WIRE 688 1824 608 1824
WIRE 848 1824 768 1824
WIRE 320 1856 320 1824
WIRE 368 1856 368 1808
WIRE 640 1856 640 1792
WIRE 640 1856 368 1856
WIRE 688 1856 640 1856
WIRE 848 1856 848 1824
WIRE 848 1856 768 1856
WIRE 1024 1856 1024 1808
WIRE 1264 1856 1264 1600
WIRE 1264 1856 1024 1856
WIRE 2080 1856 2080 1824
WIRE 848 1888 848 1856
WIRE 256 1936 256 1680
WIRE 368 1936 256 1936
WIRE 512 1936 368 1936
WIRE 1024 1936 960 1936
WIRE 2208 1936 2080 1936
WIRE 288 1968 288 1712
WIRE 320 1968 288 1968
WIRE 464 1968 320 1968
WIRE 2080 1968 2080 1936
WIRE 368 1984 368 1936
WIRE 512 1984 512 1936
WIRE 1024 1984 1024 1936
WIRE 320 2000 320 1968
WIRE 464 2000 464 1968
WIRE 976 2000 608 2000
WIRE 976 2048 640 2048
WIRE 320 2080 320 2048
WIRE 464 2080 464 2048
WIRE 464 2080 320 2080
WIRE 512 2080 512 2064
WIRE 608 2080 608 2000
WIRE 608 2080 512 2080
WIRE 688 2080 608 2080
WIRE 848 2080 768 2080
WIRE 2080 2080 2080 2048
WIRE 320 2112 320 2080
WIRE 368 2112 368 2064
WIRE 640 2112 640 2048
WIRE 640 2112 368 2112
WIRE 688 2112 640 2112
WIRE 848 2112 848 2080
WIRE 848 2112 768 2112
WIRE 1024 2112 1024 2064
WIRE 1264 2112 1264 1856
WIRE 1264 2112 1024 2112
WIRE 848 2144 848 2112
WIRE 2208 2160 2080 2160
WIRE 256 2192 256 1936
WIRE 368 2192 256 2192
WIRE 512 2192 368 2192
WIRE 1024 2192 960 2192
WIRE 2080 2192 2080 2160
WIRE 288 2224 288 1968
WIRE 320 2224 288 2224
WIRE 464 2224 320 2224
WIRE 368 2240 368 2192
WIRE 512 2240 512 2192
WIRE 1024 2240 1024 2192
WIRE 320 2256 320 2224
WIRE 464 2256 464 2224
WIRE 976 2256 608 2256
WIRE 976 2304 640 2304
WIRE 2080 2304 2080 2272
WIRE 320 2336 320 2304
WIRE 464 2336 464 2304
WIRE 464 2336 320 2336
WIRE 512 2336 512 2320
WIRE 608 2336 608 2256
WIRE 608 2336 512 2336
WIRE 688 2336 608 2336
WIRE 848 2336 768 2336
WIRE 320 2368 320 2336
WIRE 368 2368 368 2320
WIRE 640 2368 640 2304
WIRE 640 2368 368 2368
WIRE 688 2368 640 2368
WIRE 848 2368 848 2336
WIRE 848 2368 768 2368
WIRE 1024 2368 1024 2320
WIRE 1264 2368 1264 2112
WIRE 1264 2368 1024 2368
WIRE 2208 2384 2080 2384
WIRE 848 2400 848 2368
WIRE 2080 2416 2080 2384
WIRE 1264 2432 1264 2368
WIRE 2080 2528 2080 2496
WIRE 1264 2560 1264 2512
FLAG 2080 672 0
FLAG 128 336 CHANNEL_SELECT
IOPIN 128 336 In
FLAG 2208 512 CHANNEL_SELECT
FLAG 128 576 0
FLAG 320 576 0
FLAG 320 832 0
FLAG 960 656 IN2
IOPIN 960 656 In
FLAG 320 1088 0
FLAG 960 912 IN3
IOPIN 960 912 In
FLAG 320 1344 0
FLAG 960 1168 IN4
IOPIN 960 1168 In
FLAG 320 1600 0
FLAG 960 1424 IN5
IOPIN 960 1424 In
FLAG 960 400 IN1
IOPIN 960 400 In
FLAG 1408 400 MUX_COMMON
IOPIN 1408 400 Out
FLAG 2080 960 0
FLAG 2208 816 IN1
FLAG 2080 1184 0
FLAG 2208 1040 IN2
FLAG 2080 1408 0
FLAG 2208 1264 IN3
FLAG 2080 1632 0
FLAG 2208 1488 IN4
FLAG 2080 1856 0
FLAG 2208 1712 IN5
FLAG 848 608 0
FLAG 848 864 0
FLAG 848 1120 0
FLAG 848 1376 0
FLAG 848 1632 0
FLAG 1264 2560 0
FLAG 320 1856 0
FLAG 960 1680 IN6
IOPIN 960 1680 In
FLAG 320 2112 0
FLAG 960 1936 IN7
IOPIN 960 1936 In
FLAG 320 2368 0
FLAG 960 2192 IN8
IOPIN 960 2192 In
FLAG 848 1888 0
FLAG 848 2144 0
FLAG 848 2400 0
FLAG 2080 2080 0
FLAG 2208 1936 IN6
FLAG 2080 2304 0
FLAG 2208 2160 IN7
FLAG 2080 2528 0
FLAG 2208 2384 IN8
SYMBOL voltage 2080 544 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 3 -4 177 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PWL(0 0 +10ms 10 +1ms 10 +10ms 0)
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res 1392 384 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 0.001
SYMBOL sw 368 544 M180
SYMATTR InstName S6
SYMATTR Value TH1_H
SYMBOL sw 512 544 M180
SYMATTR InstName S7
SYMATTR Value TH1_L
SYMBOL voltage 128 416 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL sw 1024 544 M180
SYMATTR InstName S8
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 800 M180
SYMATTR InstName S9
SYMATTR Value TH2_H
SYMBOL sw 512 800 M180
SYMATTR InstName S10
SYMATTR Value TH2_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 800 M180
SYMATTR InstName S11
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 1056 M180
SYMATTR InstName S12
SYMATTR Value TH3_H
SYMBOL sw 512 1056 M180
SYMATTR InstName S13
SYMATTR Value TH3_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 1056 M180
SYMATTR InstName S14
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 1312 M180
SYMATTR InstName S15
SYMATTR Value TH4_H
SYMBOL sw 512 1312 M180
SYMATTR InstName S16
SYMATTR Value TH4_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 1312 M180
SYMATTR InstName S17
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 1568 M180
SYMATTR InstName S18
SYMATTR Value TH5_H
SYMBOL sw 512 1568 M180
SYMATTR InstName S19
SYMATTR Value TH5_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 1568 M180
SYMATTR InstName S20
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL voltage 2080 832 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 0.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 1056 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value 1.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 1280 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value 2.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 1504 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMATTR Value 3.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 1728 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 4.75
SYMBOL res 784 528 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 560 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 784 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 816 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1040 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1072 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1296 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1328 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1552 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1584 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 1248 2416 R0
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL sw 368 1824 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMATTR Value TH6_H
SYMBOL sw 512 1824 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMATTR Value TH6_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 1824 M180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 2080 M180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMATTR Value TH7_H
SYMBOL sw 512 2080 M180
SYMATTR InstName S5
SYMATTR Value TH7_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 2080 M180
SYMATTR InstName S21
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL sw 368 2336 M180
SYMATTR InstName S22
SYMATTR Value TH8_H
SYMBOL sw 512 2336 M180
SYMATTR InstName S23
SYMATTR Value TH8_L
SYMBOL sw 1024 2336 M180
SYMATTR InstName S24
SYMATTR Value OUTPUT_SW
SYMBOL res 784 1808 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 1840 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 2064 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R15
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 2096 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R16
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 2320 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 3 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R17
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 784 2352 R90
WINDOW 0 17 115 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -10 0 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R18
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL voltage 2080 1952 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 5.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 2176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V9
SYMATTR Value 6.75
SYMBOL voltage 2080 2400 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V10
SYMATTR Value 7.75
TEXT 616 264 Left 3 !.tran 0 23ms 0
TEXT -400 744 Left 2 !.param select_1 = 1V\n.param select_2 = 2V\n.param select_3 = 3V\n.param select_4 = 4V\n.param select_5 = 5V\n.param select_6 = 6V\n.param select_7 = 7V\n.param select_8 = 8V\n.param select_offset = 0.2V\n \n.model TH1_L SW(Vt=select_1-select_offset)\n.model TH2_L SW(Vt=select_2-select_offset)\n.model TH3_L SW(Vt=select_3-select_offset)\n.model TH4_L SW(Vt=select_4-select_offset)\n.model TH5_L SW(Vt=select_5-select_offset)\n.model TH6_L SW(Vt=select_6-select_offset)\n.model TH7_L SW(Vt=select_7-select_offset)\n.model TH8_L SW(Vt=select_8-select_offset)\n \n.model TH1_H SW(Vt=select_1+select_offset)\n.model TH2_H SW(Vt=select_2+select_offset)\n.model TH3_H SW(Vt=select_3+select_offset)\n.model TH4_H SW(Vt=select_4+select_offset)\n.model TH5_H SW(Vt=select_5+select_offset)\n.model TH6_H SW(Vt=select_6+select_offset)\n.model TH7_H SW(Vt=select_7+select_offset)\n.model TH8_H SW(Vt=select_8+select_offset)\n \n.model OUTPUT_SW SW(Ron=0.001 Roff=1g Vt=0.1)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: LTSpice power multiplexer output]

One of the aspects that is different from the real-life bank of switches concept is that LTSpice doesn't like not having a load on a SW element.  Hence the 10K resistors and the 1Meg resistor on the output.  I would remove the latter when turning this into a component as I don't think it would be necessary for real application.

EDIT1:
The intent was to turn this into a subcircuit that could be used anywhere, which is precisely what I did.  Here it is in its application form:

[image]

EDIT2:
I thought it would be good to add an explanation of how this circuit works just in case it might be useful to others.

[image]

Each channel has two threshold detectors in the form of switches. Their operating parameters are set in the model statement. Of interest are the thresholds. I use variables to set them up. Each channel has a low and high threshold detector. In the case of the first channel, TH1_L triggers at 0.8V and TH1_H at 1.2V. The channel output switch is driven by these two detectors, which means the channel turns on when TH1_L=1 and TH1_H=0.  Here's a closeup of the action around 1 V using a ramp as an input (red). TH1_L is green and TH1_H is blue:

[image]

What I like about this is that the channel active zone is nicely centered around 1 V.  This approach also avoids cross-conduction between channels.  Here's the output showing all channels.  In this case I applied a different voltage to each channel input in order to be able to visualize what's going on.  The first channel starts at 0.75V and each succeeding channel is 1V higher.  You can clearly see there's no cross-conduction zone and we can tell exactly which channel is on in this test. We can also see what happens in out of range conditions.

[image]

The answer I selected replaces the threshold detector switches with buffers. Each buffer has a different logic threshold set. It's essentially the same except that I wanted to have precise control of the channel switch turn on window. This could be done with the buffer approach and maybe also using switch Vh settings creatively. I'll investigate.

Comment: Why don't you just construct a custom symbol and a .lib/.mod file for it? Also, those switch models that LTspice supports provide a variety of methods for transitioning. You might use that fact as a way of avoiding those megOhm and 10k resistors. (If you are careful about how you write your model, anyway.) You seem to be savvy enough already to work out the details. So I'm wondering if there's another question I'm not getting from what you wrote because I'm not good enough at reading between lines (or else my crystal ball remains broken.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did.  I just edited the question to show the symbol being applied.    Just looking for advice/opinion.  I am comfortable with LTSpice but by no mean an expert, still learning something new every day.  I am particularly ignorant of potential unintended consequences, such as what was mentioned below about what can happen if you go with the default Vh value of 0.  Thanks.

Comment: @martin's Do my eyes deceive me: `C:\Users\admin\...`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @martin's I was referring to the usage of the `admin` user. Similar to `root` in Unix/Linux. At any rate, I've updated the answer: the circuit is simplifed even more, but some care is needed now.

Comment: Got it.  Not a big deal in this case.  It's Windows 10.  It's just a name, I still have to escalate permissions.  I could have named the user account "goofy" (which would have been far more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> LTSpice doesn't like not having a load on a SW element. Hence the 10K resistors and the 1Meg resistor on the output

You probably connected them diferently, but as long as both inputs of the VCSW are connected, there is no need for a load. At the worst, the error log will show a warning about a floating node (and warnings are not errors).

That said, here's another version of what (I think) you're trying to achieve. It's bidirectional, despite what the picture shows:

[image: test]

As it is, the voltage at the control pin, `V(ctl)`, selects an input based on the equivalent of `int()`: if `int(V(ctl))==1` then it connects the first input (maybe I should have labeled them `1, 2, 3, 4`, instead of `a, b, c, d`) with `out`, if `int(V(ctl))==2` then it connects `b` <-> `out`, etc (see `V(test)` for comparison, its only purpose in the schematic). Anything outside the range means all switches are off.

In your schematic, you're using the switches without `vh` specified. That defaults to `0`, which means an abrupt switching around the transition. You should know that there are very good reasons not to choose that behaviour ([read this](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F), for example). Because of this I have added `vh=-0.5` (also be sure to read the manual under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > S. ...*, especially the part right beneath the first table). To make use in full of this smooth switching, you should also add `tau=<value>` to the buffers. This way you can eliminate cross-conduction, except for an insignificant portion. For a more pronounced effect, set `vt` higher and `vh=vt-1`. Here's how it looks with `tau=1m` for the buffers and `vt={x} vh={x-1}` for a `.step param x 0.5 0.9 0.1`:

[image: cc]

There may be cases where an abrupt switching is needed, for example to see the behaviour of a resonant tank, but, in general, a non-negative `vh` will work in simple cases like this, but when involved in more comples ones, particularly in feedback systems, it can be a cause for "*timestep too small*" errors.

Your choice for `Ron` and `Roff` is a very good one: the values won't influence the output that much while keeping the dynamic range of 1e12 or less. In case you need heavier loads, you could tweak it to be (e.g.) `Ron=10u Roff=10meg`, but don't forget about the negative `vh`.

Not lastly, all this can be encapsulated in a subcircuit with an appropriate symbol, see [this excellent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372297/95619) on how to do it. The only needed parts are the buffers, `A[1:n]`, and the switches, `S[1:n]` (and the `.model` card), while the nodes are `a, b, c, ..., n`, `out`, and `ctl`. You may add a `1g` resistor to ground inside the circuit, for those cases where the `ctl` pin might be floating, somehow (the simulation might abort with an error). As I said, it's bidirectional, so `out` is not such a good choice for a label.

---

There is a reason why you got an error without a resistor. Referring to your [last picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml1xH.png), you tried to feed `V2` through `S6` straight into `S8`'s input, but VCSWs are pure voltage mode: their inputs don't consume current, and current monitoring is disabled for this reason -- just try to feed a voltage source straight into a pin of a VCSW and try to plot the current through the wire (not through the source). Therefore `S6`, without `R2`, has no effect, but with it, it can act as a controlled voltage divider.

Also because of the pure voltage mode, leaving any control input floating may result in a "*singular matrix*" error, since it is expected that the pin must have a potential, of any kind. It might work, it might not, but to be safe the only cure is to add something, anything, even a capacitor.

Regarding your comments and recent edits, if you need the switches to have a larger window, then you can add another batch of buffers to help. Plotted against `int(V(ctl))` you can see that they turn on/off symmetrically around the transitions:

[image: gapped]

This can be added as a parameter, here `thres`, for better control. Of course, the values don't need to be `1`±`thres`, `2`±`thres`, etc, they can be any other: `3.14`±`thres`, `1.618`±`thres`, ... In fact, `thres` doesn't even need to be symmetrical around the value, you can always add `thres1` and `thres2`. You can also make the thresholds overlap, you'll see nice cross-conduction. Here's the source for the `.asc` file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1116 680
WIRE 576 -432 512 -432
WIRE 704 -432 656 -432
WIRE 752 -432 704 -432
WIRE 896 -432 864 -432
WIRE 896 -400 896 -432
WIRE 576 -304 512 -304
WIRE 704 -304 704 -432
WIRE 704 -304 656 -304
WIRE 144 -288 80 -288
WIRE 352 -288 288 -288
WIRE 896 -272 896 -320
WIRE 144 -160 80 -160
WIRE 352 -160 288 -160
WIRE 576 -160 512 -160
WIRE 704 -160 704 -304
WIRE 704 -160 656 -160
WIRE 576 -32 512 -32
WIRE 704 -32 704 -160
WIRE 704 -32 656 -32
WIRE 208 112 192 112
WIRE 320 112 272 112
WIRE 592 112 576 112
WIRE 704 112 656 112
WIRE 32 176 -32 176
WIRE 192 192 192 112
WIRE 208 192 192 192
WIRE 320 192 272 192
WIRE 576 192 576 112
WIRE 592 192 576 192
WIRE 704 192 656 192
WIRE 192 272 192 192
WIRE 208 272 192 272
WIRE 320 272 272 272
WIRE 576 272 576 192
WIRE 592 272 576 272
WIRE 704 272 656 272
WIRE 144 352 -32 352
WIRE 192 352 192 272
WIRE 192 352 144 352
WIRE 208 352 192 352
WIRE 320 352 272 352
WIRE 576 352 576 272
WIRE 576 352 528 352
WIRE 592 352 576 352
WIRE 704 352 656 352
FLAG -32 432 0
FLAG 144 352 ctl
FLAG 320 112 c1
FLAG 320 192 c2
FLAG 320 272 c3
FLAG 320 352 c4
FLAG 592 -384 c1
FLAG 640 -384 _c1
FLAG 512 -432 a
FLAG 752 -432 out
FLAG 592 -256 c2
FLAG 640 -256 _c2
FLAG 512 -304 b
FLAG 592 -112 c3
FLAG 640 -112 _c3
FLAG 512 -160 c
FLAG 592 16 c4
FLAG 640 16 _c4
FLAG 512 -32 d
FLAG 80 -208 0
FLAG 144 -288 a
FLAG 80 -80 0
FLAG 144 -160 c
FLAG 288 -208 0
FLAG 352 -288 b
FLAG 288 -80 0
FLAG 352 -160 d
FLAG 896 -272 0
FLAG 864 -432 out
FLAG -32 256 0
FLAG 32 176 test
FLAG 704 112 _c1
FLAG 704 192 _c2
FLAG 704 272 _c3
FLAG 704 352 _c4
FLAG 528 352 ctl
SYMBOL voltage -32 336 R0
WINDOW 0 35 32 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value pwl 0 0 .5 5 1 0
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 48 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={1-thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL sw 672 -432 M270
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL sw 672 -304 M270
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL sw 672 -160 M270
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL sw 672 -32 M270
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMBOL voltage 80 -304 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 80 -176 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 3
SYMBOL voltage 288 -304 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 288 -176 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value 4
SYMBOL res 880 -416 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL bv -32 160 R0
WINDOW 0 37 39 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value v=int(v(ctl))
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 128 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={2-thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 208 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={3-thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 288 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={4-thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 592 48 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={1+thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 592 128 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={2+thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A7
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 592 208 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={3+thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A8
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 592 288 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={4+thres} tau={tau}
SYMATTR InstName A9
TEXT -64 -344 Left 2 !.tran 0 1 0
TEXT -64 -424 Left 2 !.model sw sw ron=1m roff=1g vt=0.5 vh=-0.5
TEXT -64 -384 Left 2 !.parma thres=0.25 tau=1m
```

---

If you know the controlling voltage doesn't dally too long in the transition regions, half of the buffers can be eliminated. I'm not sure it can be simplified further (but I'd love to be proven wrong). The changes are in the addition of `vhigh` for the buffers, and a modification for `vt` and `vh` for the switches:

[image: simp]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1116 680
WIRE 576 -432 512 -432
WIRE 704 -432 656 -432
WIRE 752 -432 704 -432
WIRE 896 -432 864 -432
WIRE 896 -400 896 -432
WIRE 576 -304 512 -304
WIRE 704 -304 704 -432
WIRE 704 -304 656 -304
WIRE 144 -288 80 -288
WIRE 352 -288 288 -288
WIRE 896 -272 896 -320
WIRE 144 -160 80 -160
WIRE 352 -160 288 -160
WIRE 576 -160 512 -160
WIRE 704 -160 704 -304
WIRE 704 -160 656 -160
WIRE 576 -32 512 -32
WIRE 704 -32 704 -160
WIRE 704 -32 656 -32
WIRE 208 112 192 112
WIRE 320 112 272 112
WIRE 32 176 -32 176
WIRE 192 192 192 112
WIRE 208 192 192 192
WIRE 320 192 272 192
WIRE 192 272 192 192
WIRE 208 272 192 272
WIRE 320 272 272 272
WIRE 144 352 -32 352
WIRE 192 352 192 272
WIRE 192 352 144 352
WIRE 208 352 192 352
WIRE 320 352 272 352
FLAG -32 432 0
FLAG 144 352 ctl
FLAG 320 112 c1
FLAG 320 192 c2
FLAG 320 272 c3
FLAG 320 352 c4
FLAG 592 -384 c1
FLAG 640 -384 ctl
FLAG 512 -432 a
FLAG 752 -432 out
FLAG 592 -256 c2
FLAG 640 -256 ctl
FLAG 512 -304 b
FLAG 592 -112 c3
FLAG 640 -112 ctl
FLAG 512 -160 c
FLAG 592 16 c4
FLAG 640 16 ctl
FLAG 512 -32 d
FLAG 80 -208 0
FLAG 144 -288 a
FLAG 80 -80 0
FLAG 144 -160 c
FLAG 288 -208 0
FLAG 352 -288 b
FLAG 288 -80 0
FLAG 352 -160 d
FLAG 896 -272 0
FLAG 864 -432 out
FLAG -32 256 0
FLAG 32 176 test
SYMBOL voltage -32 336 R0
WINDOW 0 35 32 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value pwl 0 0 .5 5 1 0
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 48 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={1-thres} tau={tau} vhigh={1+thres}
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL sw 672 -432 M270
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL sw 672 -304 M270
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL sw 672 -160 M270
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL sw 672 -32 M270
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMBOL voltage 80 -304 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 80 -176 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 3
SYMBOL voltage 288 -304 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 288 -176 R0
WINDOW 0 31 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value 4
SYMBOL res 880 -416 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL bv -32 160 R0
WINDOW 0 37 39 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value v=int(v(ctl))
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 128 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={2-thres} tau={tau} vhigh={2+thres}
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 208 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={3-thres} tau={tau} vhigh={3+thres}
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 208 288 R0
WINDOW 3 20 90 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 46 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ref={4-thres} tau={tau} vhigh={4+thres}
SYMATTR InstName A4
TEXT -64 -344 Left 2 !.tran 0 1 0
TEXT -64 -424 Left 2 !.model sw sw ron=1m roff=1g vt=0 vh=-10m
TEXT -64 -384 Left 2 !.parma thres=0.25 tau=1m
```

Comment: The convergence link is interesting. Great pointer on specifying Vh to avoid issues. I like your circuit, it's simple. Didn't realize you could specify a threshold for buf1. I also like your use of sequential buf outputs to turn on the channel switches. That said, I used low and high threshold detectors (THn_L and THn_H) in my schematic in order to avoid cross conduction issues. I have fine control of the on/off window of each channel switch. For example, the first channel is designed to be on between 0.8 and 1.2 V. The second channel 1.8 and 2.2, etc. Probably not the best solution.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because of the idea to simplify the circuit and the very useful advice. As is always the case, there are myriad solutions for something like this. It will be interesting to see what others might come up with.

Comment: BTW, on the point about choosing switch on/off resistance. I ended-up having to increase the off resistance to 1gig. In actual application I saw that the circuit under test ended-up trying to drive all power sources a little bit and the simulator ground to a halt because of this (picoseconds/s). When I set roff to 1 gig the simulation got back to full speed. There might be some other fundamental issue with my model. I'll continue to fine tune and see how far I can get.

Comment: Sorry, one last comment with reference to the need for a load. What I was referring to was mainly that my two threshold detector switches (THn_L and THn_H) failed to turn on/off the channel switch (OUTPUT_SW) unless I added some resistance go GND. If I remove those resistors the circuit does not work. The mux output resistor is not an issue as that pin will never be disconnected from a source/load in practice. That said, I like your idea of adding a large value resistor to the model just to keep everyone happy.

Comment: +1 for the light-background, high-contrast images.

Comment: @martin's I've updated the answer given you recent changes and comments. If you got crawling speeds (ps/s) and increasing the resistor to `1g` solved it, it's probably something else that's ill-conditioned.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thank you for the vote, but I hope you won't get negativity from other users on account of apparent shallowness (no veiled accusation). But if you will, I'll back you up. ;-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen ¬‿¬

Comment: Comment on the light vs. dark background screen grabs.  I actually thought of redoing the graphs with a light background.  What changed my mind is that I posted high resolution images which, when clicked, expand out and look fine.  I didn't want to discombobulate the settings for posting, it didn't seem necessary.  Should I replace the images?  I have no rigid opinion on this one way or the other other than the obvious one, which is that the images have to be useful.  I felt that the high resolution pop-out covered that well.  Wrong?

Comment: @martin's I pretty much see things as you just wrote. If you want to see the image better, you can click on it. I do make sure that clicking on it is readable and will replace it, if not. One *could* go to a lot more work to learn about how images are prepared and displayed by the stackexchange server and then go the extra steps required to use photo editing software to make images that will display better, plus the extra work within other programs generating images to improve them before all this extra work happens. But I don't want to be ***that*** expert just to post a question or answer.

Comment: @jonk The problem with pictures is that they are fixed, so if they are made to fit some theme, say light, then someone else's dark theme will look awful. SVG could be nice, maybe some XOR kind, but even those will look strange given the colour inversions. The built-in tool allows for a uniform appearance, but it's still a screenshot. I know there's a topic on meta, but I fear it's not the sort of goal that can be reached. So, the gray I use just might come somewhere in-between. Might not.

Comment: @martin's When replying to someone, use the ping operator, `@`, otherwise the user will not be notified. For more difficult names, use `@<TAB>` to cycle beteen them. If `<TAB>` doesn't seem to work then `@` is not needed, but only then.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Got it!  Thanks.