# LTspice - Create a subcircuit and modify its own parameters

Tags: ltspice

I have created a subcircuit on LTspice. Here it is:

[image]

It has a lot parameters that I would like to adjust.

Her is the netlist:

[image]

Just have to create the symbol and it is done. Here it is:

[image]

Nevertheless I do not have access to the parameters... How can I do for accessing the parameters of my components? Is it also possible to set parameter value by default?

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had a similar question before. At any rate, just `RCLick` on the symbol (or `Ctrl+RClick`) and simply add `n=<value> Lleakp=<value> ...`, then optionally double click on the entry in the `Vis.` column to make it visible and more accessible in the schematic. If you need those values paramterized in the top level schematic, simply add your `.param` statements then enter `n={<param>} Lleakp={<param>} ...`, and so on. BTW, this is also described in the help under `Schematic Capture > Editing Components`.

Comment: Really, you should [take a look here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372297/95619) for a much better explanation.

Comment: Apparently, i m loosing my long term memory ... That's bad ! Thank you for your comment :D

Comment: @Jess I may well just be me; decrepitude might be earlier than I thought.

Comment: I do not know. I was looking for a question on my own profil but I do not find it but it is possible that the topic name is not really descriptive of the above problem.  So you may be right ! (BTW by looking for it, I saw all the questions that I posted ! And all the progress that I have done thanks to the community ! THANK YOU SO MUCH)

Comment: @Jess Congratulations and keep it up! Don't forget that doing that carries an implicit trial, one of a rather insidious nature: the equivalent of the surface of a lake for Narcissus. :-)

Comment: Well there is still a long way to do in electronics before falling in love of me like Narcissus :D