# How can I design a beta modulator block

Tags: amplifier, resistors, switches, modulation, demodulation

I am simulating a block beta modulator, but the problem is to switch uses in that block. What component do I have to use in place of U3? I did not find this type of any component in LTspice library and also also given any help about this circuit in reference articles.

[image: this is circuit diagram of beta modulator block]

Image source: Monani, Ravi; Rogers, Brian; Rezaei, Amin; and Hedayatipour, Ava. **Implementation of Chaotic Encryption Architecture on FPGA for On-Chip Secure Communication**. *IEEE Green Energy and Systems Conference IGESC*. https://par.nsf.gov/biblio/10437437

Comment: Usha Kumari - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source citation and link & added it. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the image. It has no inverting amplifiers, no summing amplifier, and the amplifiers that are shown have fixed gains. That is 0 for 3. Is that the correct image for the description?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch.
There is an excellent answer by jonk about how to make a SPDT switch in LTspice:
[SPDT in LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372278/spdt-in-ltspice)

There are also some Analog provided components that will model a switch. Below is one such example for a SPDT switch.
[image]